# How to retrieve values from specific lines of an ascii file

Tags: python, numpy

I have several ascii files which looks like this-

```
001, 12:04, ...., ...., ...., ....
001, 12:05, ...., ...., ...., ....
001, 12:06, ...., ...., ...., ....
002, 12:07, ...., ...., ...., ....
002, 12:08, ...., ...., ...., ....
002, 12:09, ...., ...., ...., ....
002, 12:10, ...., ...., ...., ....
002, 12:11, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:12, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:13, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:14, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:15, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:16, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:17, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:18, ...., ...., ...., ....
003, 12:19, ...., ...., ...., ....
```

And so on. What I would like is to get the fifth values of the lines before it changes to the next one. For example,the fifth values of these lines and so on..

`001, 12:06, ...., ...., ...., ....
 002, 12:11, ...., ...., ...., ....
 003, 12:19, ...., ...., ...., ....`

Any help please using python, numpy?

Answer (score 3):

```
lines_as_string = """001, 12:04, ...., ...., ...., 1...
001, 12:05, ...., ...., ...., 2...
001, 12:06, ...., ...., 2..., 3...
002, 12:07, ...., ...., 1..., 1...
002, 12:08, ...., ...., 2..., 2...
002, 12:09, ...., ...., 3..., 3...
002, 12:10, ...., ...., 4..., 4...
002, 12:11, ...., ...., 5..., 5...
003, 12:12, ...., ...., 5..., 1...
003, 12:13, ...., ...., 1..., 2...
003, 12:14, ...., ...., 2..., 3...
003, 12:15, ...., ...., 3..., 4...
003, 12:16, ...., ...., 4..., 5...
003, 12:17, ...., ...., 5..., 6...
003, 12:18, ...., ...., 6..., 7...
003, 12:19, ...., ...., 7..., 8..."""


last_fives = [v for k,v in sorted({l[0]:l[5] for l in [a.split(', ') for a in lines_as_string.split('\n')]}.items())]
```

this is what its doing broken up into more readable steps.

```
lines = []
# split into rows
for line in lines_as_string.split('\n'):
    #split into columns
    columns = line.split(', ')
    lines.append(columns)

last_lines = {}
# make a dict where row[0] -> row[5]
for row in lines:
    # since they are ordered already,
    # previous lines get overwritten
    last_lines[row[0]] = row[5]

# create a list sorted by the original keys
last_fives = []
for k,v in sorted(last_lines.items()):
    last_fives.append(v)
```

Comment: @ShawnMehan thats the nicest thing anyone has said to me all day.